# C1189: #error : WINDOWS.H already included. MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, atl

I'm building a C++ project which includes 2 libraries whom implicitly include for 2 times `windows.h` :

1. afxwin.h
2. atlbase.h (not sure)

Knowing that I need these two libraries into my project, how do I to get around this issue?

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: Do you include `afxwin.h` prior to including `atlbase.h`? According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173974/en-us the mfc includes should be prior to the atl.

Comment: @halex, If I do so, I'll get a weird error that I couldn't find a solution which I've had mentionned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720864/c2039-catlservicemodulet-is-not-a-member-of-atl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hide mentioned libraries using some facade interface that these includes are not visible in the same compilation unit.

Comment: Thanks for your response Bogdan. Would you please more detail it?

Comment: @user3289501: I would create two interfaces, let's say Lib1 and Lib2, and hide using of problematic headers in theirs implementation. Let's say that afxwin.h gives you method foo(), so you could add method Lib1::foo() which uses the original foo() inside. Generally speaking any operation which uses problematic libraries can be hidden in such way.

Comment: @Bogdan Could you give a more practical explanation? I dont fully understand what you mean.

Comment: @k4rlsson Let's say you want to use CString::Trim from atlstr.h. Let's say you cannot use it in-place because of headers conflicts. So I suggest to make a header trim_string.h with function declaration TrimString(char*) and inside trim_string.cpp make a TrimString definition which uses CString. This way you can hide CString and atlstr.h from the rest of your code by using your facade.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when building a Win32 app in visual studio 2010. A solution that worked for me was:

1. Open stdafx.h
2. Replace `#include <windows.h>` with `#include <afxwin.h>`

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time before trying to understand "Why I can't use libraries with WIN types definitions and inclusion Windows.h" in my MFC application with #include <afxwin.h> in stdafx.h
Finally, I found the magic wrong inclusion order into one from 300+ files.

```
//MyModuleName.cpp
#include "MyModuleName.h"
#include "..\stdafx.h"     // <--- this must be always first
```

after the fix, all external libs etc work properly even Windows.h in headers

```
//MyModuleName.cpp
#include "..\stdafx.h"     // <--- this must be always first
#include "MyModuleName.h"
```